# Replacing Windows logon screen with metro style application

Tags: vb.net, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml, .net-4.5

Actually I am developing a metro style app (WinRT App) that is based on PC security.

Therefore i want my metro application to be run instead of windows logon screen because this metro app will provide different security methods such as Face Detection, Touch-Password etc..

Geeks, just help me out..

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I would say it's not possible.

Answer (score 2):

WinRT applications do not have access to enough of the system to serve as a logon screen.

Comment: OR can i call a simple form application instead of windows logon screen ???

And then can i call my metro app through that form application ???